Exporting test cases in TFS Version 15.105.27412.0 in a readable format
I'm trying to export test cases from TFS Version 15.105.27412.0. I have tried to do this through both Excel and Visual Studio 2022, but I run into the same issue in both places.
The test cases are exported with pretty much no issue, but the steps are exported in a format, such that, there is no way to differentiate an action from an expected result.
For example, see the following test case example (dummy values):
Action : Expected Result

asdfasdf :
ssdfgsdfg : sdgsdfg
asdfasdf :
asdfasdf : fghjifghj
:

This test cases gets export to Excel in the following format:
<div><div><p>asdfasdf</p></div></div><div><div><p>ssdfgsdfg </p></div></div><div><p>sdfgsdfg </p></div><div><div><p>asdfasdf </p></div></div><div><p> </p></div><div><div><p>asdfasdf </p></div></div><p> fghjfghj</p><div><div><p> </p></div></div><div><p> </p></div>

There doesn't seem to be a way to extract/differentiate an action from an expected result from this output.
any insight/help on this would be much appreciated.
I've scowered the internet for any insight on this and have come up empty on anyone else even encountering this issue. The reason I'm doing this is because we are migrating test case repositories

The TFS Version 15.XX should be the TFS 2017 instead of TFS2015. I checked my TFS 2017 version:

If you can update the TFS2017 to at least Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2 or update 3, you can install and use the Offline Test Execution extension.  Previous Versions TFS Downloads page: Here.

It can show the steps one by one as shown in the screenshot.

You can also explore other extension from the marketspace.
